# Using CSS preprocessor with material design

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-design

I have yet to use a CSS preprocessor with a react-redux project, but that is about to change.

I noticed in CRA facebook docs, I can install `node-sass`, but I want to use Material Design, but I noticed in the Material Design docs, I would need to configure Webpack in order to work with MD and `node-sass`.

And do I even have to use `node-sass`?

Does that mean I would have to do an `npm run eject` then? Or just do `npm install webpack@3.x.x`?

In summary, I wish to use Material Design with a CSS preprocessor in a React-Redux project. How can I proceed?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/ Does this work for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean I would have to do an npm run eject then? Or just do npm install webpack@3.x.x?

With the new CRA v2.0 that was released last October, you do not have to run an `npm run eject` to work with CSS preprocessor.

> And do I even have to use node-sass?

Yes, you can do an `npm install node-sass` and then change your `css` files to `scss` and create `scss` extension files for future CSS files.

Material Design is a design language created for Google Android’s new OS which was announced in Summer 2014, but appears to only now be catching steam in the rest of the industry.

Essentially these are design specs that Google put together and have since inspired various Material Design type of libraries that you can work with.

There are Material Design inspired CSS frameworks that you can avail yourself of to work with Material Design. Here are the following libraries:

1. **Materialize** is arguably one of the most well-known Material Design CSS frameworks out there. Developed by a team of highly skilled, passionate students, Materialize is widely used with many available third party themes.
2. **MUI** is quite popular as well. Although an individual effort, it raises the bar by providing out-of-the-box support for Angular, React and WebComponents. The detailed documentation also deserves a thumbs-up.
3. **Surface** is a minimal, super lightweight CSS framework adopting Material Design, don't expect extensive documentation though.
4. **Material Foundation**, although documentation out there seems abandoned.
5. **Material Design Lite** was published by Google engineers, therefore you can expect consistency and close alignment with Material Design concepts.
6. **Material Components for the Web** is the successor to Material Design Lite and is maintained by Google engineers and designers. Its high-level goals include modularity, adherence to the Material Design guidelines and seamless integration with other JavaScript frameworks and libraries.
7. **Material-UI**, not really a CSS framework in the strict sense of the word, an interesting approach to implementing Material Design using React components.